# Remove "Private" + ":" in title does not work

Tags: filters, get-the-title

I would like to remove the "private" prefix for each post title.
I found the filter [here](https://wp-mix.com/remove-private-post-titles/).
I managed to removed the word "Private" but when I concatenate with " : ". 
That does not work anymore. 
I checked `$title` value before the `str_replace` and it´s already translated with " : ".

```
Class FrontEnd{

    protected function front_end_init() {
        add_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'remove_private_prefix' ) );
    }

    public static function remove_private_prefix( $title ) {
        $title = str_replace( __( 'Private' ) . " : ", '', $title);
        return $title;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest answer is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'private_title_format', function ( $format ) {
    return '%s';
} );
```

It uses the `private_title_format` to change the format of the title to just the post title, without any unnecessary classes or functions.

Comment: Works perfectly whereas a few others I tried didn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on this [post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-privateprotected-from-post-titles/)

```
Class FrontEnd{

    protected function front_end_init() {
        add_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'remove_title_prefix' ) );
    }

    public static function remove_title_prefix( $title ) {
        $title = esc_attr($title);

        $findthese = array(
            '#['  . __("Protected") . ' : ]#',
            '#[' . __("Private") . ' : ]#'
        );
        $replacewith = array(
            '', // What to replace "Protected:" with
            '' // What to replace "Private:" with
        );

        $title = preg_replace($findthese, $replacewith, $title);
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use [`private_title_format`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/private_title_format/) - and [`protected_title_format`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/protected_title_format/) for password-protected posts..

Comment: The original problem was that you had a space before the colon: `__( 'Private' ) . " : ",`. Should just be `__( 'Private' ) . ": ",`.  This is overkill. But using the correct filters would be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sally CJ said, A better way is to used the function [private_title_format](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/private_title_format/).
So...

If you can set the `WP_Post`, you can use this code line :

`apply_filters( 'private_title_format', "", $post );`

If you do not know the $post for some reason like for my example, you can overwrite the filter like this:

```
Class FrontEnd{

    protected function front_end_init() {
        add_filter( 'private_title_format', array( $this, 'remove_prefix_private_post_title' ), 10, 2 );
    }

   public function remove_prefix_private_post_title( $format, $post ){
        return '%s';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space before the colon, so " : " becomes ": ".
Or use a superior method like shea's.